# Display a popover inside a div parent with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm writing in angularJS and I couldn't find a comfortable solution for this issue-
I have a `div` element with `overflow: hidden` property (since i'm using internal scrollbar) and inside that `div` I have a `dropdown` menu, triggered by a button click.
unfortunately, the `dropdown` in partially hidden (since it is exceeding the borders of its `div` parent.

The best solution i've found so far is to add the popover dynamically to the body and calculate its position for every button click, but it is a bit complicated since i'm also using a scroller...

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!
Tammy

Comment: Do you have sample html demostrating the problem?

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/894MK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't be able to do it without either removing `overflow: hidden;` property, or use `absolute` positions for your div and dropdown menu, which can be a bit tricky (make some search, there is a lot of topics on Stackoverflow).

But you can achieve it with `position: fixed;`, knowing that it will depend on the browser ; see a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Nf7u4/